# How to get Dialogflow Flow ID?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

The url of any flow and page I navigate to/stand on ends with:
`flows/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/flow_creation?flowType=STANDARD`
I can't extract the flow nor the page id from the url. as the flow id is always the default flow.

I can get the page ID using the code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/dialogflow-cx/list-page.js)

but I still can't get different flow ids other than the default flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the flow or getting it using the CX API:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFs1e.png)